# The union of two sigma algebra is never a sigma algebra unless one is contained in the other.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I came across the statement in a book i cannot find right now (as an exercise) that the union of two sigma algebras is never a sigma sigma algebra unless one is contained in the other. It seems like a simple statement to prove, but I have tried in vain to prove it.

The conditions given mean that for two sigma algebras $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ we have that $\exists A \text{ s.t. } A \in \Sigma_1 \text{ and } A \notin \Sigma_2$ similarly $\exists B \text{ s.t. } B \in \Sigma_2 \text{ and } B \notin \Sigma_1$ with $A \neq B$. Now to show that $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is not a sigma algebra we might proceed by showing either $A \cap B, A \cup B$ is not in it. But how to proceed, assuming that either $A$ or $B$ may be non-atomic.